# Unique features between multiple lists

Tags: python, list, set, unique

I am trying to find the unique differences between 5 different lists.

I have seen multiple examples of how to find differences between two lists but have not been able to apply this to multiple lists.

It has been easy to find the similarities between 5 lists.

Example:

```
list(set(hr1) & set(hr2) & set(hr4) & set(hr8) & set(hr24))
```

However, I want to figure out how to determine the unique features for each set.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Surprised this has never been asked before

Comment: This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49118803/307454) should work, but for some reason, it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How's this? Say we have input lists `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `[3, 4, 5, 6]`, and `[3, 4, 7, 8]`. We would want to pull out `[1, 2]` from the first list, `[5, 6]` from the second list, and `[7, 8]` from the third list.

```
from itertools import chain

A_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
A_2 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
A_3 = [3, 4, 7, 8]

# Collect the input lists for use with chain below
all_lists = [A_1, A_2, A_3]

for A in (A_1, A_2, A_3):
  # Combine all the lists into one
  super_list = list(chain(*all_lists))
  # Remove the items from the list under consideration
  for x in A:
    super_list.remove(x)
  # Get the unique items remaining in the combined list
  super_set = set(super_list)
  # Compute the unique items in this list and print them
  uniques = set(A) - super_set
  print(sorted(uniques))
```

Comment: Another grad student who I work with used this code and it worked great as well! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Can you help answer a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118597/code-to-find-unique-elements-among-lists-sets/49120680#49120680)?

Comment: I adopted this method to check for unwanted similarities in lists that should all have different elements by changing `uniques = set(A) - super_set` to `in_common = set(A).intersection(super_list)`

Answer (score 4):

Could this help? I m assuming a list of lists to illustrate this example. But you can modify the datastructure to cater to your needs

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

list_of_lists = [
    [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    [4,5,6,7,8,8],
    [8,9,2,1,3]
]
counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(set, list_of_lists)))
uniques_list = [[x for x in lst if counts[x]==1] for lst in list_of_lists]
#uniques_list = [[0], [6, 7], [9]]
```

Edit (Based on some useful comments):

```
counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
unique_list = [k for k, c in counts.items() if c == 1]
```

Comment: `counts[i]==1` should be `counts[x]==1`

Comment: Also, there is no need for `map(set, lists_of_lists)`, `chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists)` works just the same.

Comment: yeah, but if there are duplicates in the list, it just eliminates them. Just a small optimization. :)

Comment: @karthikr that's not an optimization

Comment: +1 but I think OP just wants the result as `[k for k, c in counts.items() if c == 1]`

Comment: @jamylak In the question, OP says "how to determine the unique features for each set." , so i decided to keep it as separate lists.

Comment: @karthikr but OP's example code clearly shows otherwise. Also `map(set` will only make this slower because you have to iterate through the items potentially twice now

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, will def try it out sometime today and get back.

Comment: While this is elegant, it might not be that easy to collect the unique values corresponding to the list they occurred in, whereas in the accepted answer, it is possible. The downside: since the accepted answer uses set, order is lost.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using set differencing in a comprehension

```
def f(lol):
  return [[*set(lol[i]).difference(*lol[:i], *lol[i+1:])] for i in range(len(lol))]
```

#### Example #1

```
list_of_lists = [
    [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    [4,5,6,7,8,8],
    [8,9,2,1,3]
]

f(list_of_lists)

[[0], [6, 7], [9]]
```

---

#### Example #2

```
A_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
A_2 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
A_3 = [3, 4, 7, 8]

all_lists = [A_1, A_2, A_3]

f(all_lists)

[[1, 2], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am a beginner at python and was not able to follow the suggestions above very well but was able to figure out my problem using the following code, basically just a bunch of pair-wise comparisons.

```
x1 = [x for x in hr1 if x not in hr2]
x2 = [x for x in x1 if x not in hr4]
x3 = [x for x in x2 if x not in hr8]
x4 = [x for x in x3 if x not in hr24]
len(x4)
```